# Extract the difference between two Strings

Tags: join, google-sheets, filter, split, google-sheets-formula

I'm looking to extract the difference between two cells containing strings in Google sheets.

I've tried to use the search, split and regexextract formulas with no luck.

Cell A1;
- "IE, DE, FR, GB, IT"

Cell B1;
- "IE, FR, GB"

Cell C1; (The aim is to have cell C look as follows)
- "DE, IT"**

Any suggestions or solutions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

Try in cell C1

```
=join(", " ,filter(split(A1,", "), (isna(match(split(A1,", "), split(B1, ", "),0)))))
```

and see if that works?

Comment: Glad to hear. Please also check: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=JOIN(", ", FILTER(SPLIT(A1, ", "), 
       NOT(COUNTIF(SPLIT(B1, ", "), 
                   SPLIT(A1, ", ")))))
```

[image: 0]